# variable memory location with ampersand vs pmap

Tags: c, memory

I just started deal with pointers in **C**, and one stuff confusing me...

Here is simple code:

```
int main ()
{

   long ms = 10000000;

   int  var1;
   char var2[10];

   printf("Address of var1 variable: %x\n", &var1  );
   printf("Address of var2 variable: %x\n", &var2  );
   printf("Sizeof of var2 variable: %d\n", sizeof(var2) );

   retpid();
   millisleep(ms);

   return 0;
}
```

And - it's return *var1* and *var2* memory address (virtual memory, I believe?):

```
$ ./address
Address of var1 variable: 797927b4
Address of var2 variable: 797927a0
Sizeof of var2 variable: 10
PID = 15885
```

But - when I run `pmap` - I don't see this addresses there:

```
$ pmap -x 15885
15885:   ./address
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0 r-x--  address
0000000000600000       4       4       4 rw---  address
00007fcdb6bbc000    1576     256       0 r-x--  libc-2.12.so
00007fcdb6d46000    2048       0       0 -----  libc-2.12.so
00007fcdb6f46000      16      16      16 r----  libc-2.12.so
00007fcdb6f4a000       4       4       4 rw---  libc-2.12.so
00007fcdb6f4b000      20      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
00007fcdb6f50000     128     104       0 r-x--  ld-2.12.so
00007fcdb7160000      12      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
00007fcdb716d000       8       8       8 rw---    [ anon ]
00007fcdb716f000       4       4       4 r----  ld-2.12.so
00007fcdb7170000       4       4       4 rw---  ld-2.12.so
00007fcdb7171000       4       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
00007fff79780000      84      12      12 rw---    [ stack ]
00007fff797ff000       4       4       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       4       0       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
----------------  ------  ------  ------
total kB            3924     448      80
```

What I'm miss here?

Comment: this line: printf("Address of var2 variable: %x\n", &var2  ); is rather iffy, as var2 is an array and any reference to an array name always gets the address of the array, so the '&' is not needed

Comment: those variables are on the stack, and the address of the stack is: 00007fff79780000 and those variables are NOT globally visible, so you will not see them listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think that you're missing two things:**

1. Your memory address space appears to be 64-bit, so you should use `%p` instead of `%x`.
2. The variables that you're printing are local variables, hence located somewhere in the stack.

Once you print the full 8-byte addresses, you'll see that both of them are located in the stack.

In other words, within the 84-Kbyte memory section which starts at address 0x00007fff79780000.

---

BTW, when passing a pointer to `printf`, you should generally use `%p` in any case.

It just so happen that on a 32-bit system, using `%x` yields the same result as `%p`.

Comment: Well... If I set `int  var1 = 10; char var2[10] = "memory";` at the top (this makes them global, correct?) - in result I have addresses like 0x600ab4 :-| And yes - I changed `%x` to `%p`. Also, if I set them back to `main() and with `%p` - I have "normal" adresses like `0x7fff0caba0c4` - but still can't find it then in `pmap` results...

Comment: @setevoy: To answer your questions: 1. In order to be global, they have to be outside of any function, not necessarily "on the top". They have to be only "on top" of where you use them, but that's just in order for the program to compile (not for them to become global). 2. `0x7fff0caba0c4` is not one of the addresses that you've specified in your question. What does it refer to then?

Comment: `Address of var1 variable: 0x7fffe5765f94
Address of var2 variable: 0x7fffe5765f80`

`# cat /proc/16334/maps` gives 7`fffe5752000-7fffe5767000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]` - so you are right, it's inside stack

Comment: @ barak manos I re-write script again and again, trying find solution, thus - restart it every time, and addresses now will be different

Comment: yes, about stack... but I still hope to get exactly adress :-) but... I don't sure undeerstood about globals from your comment... what is adress `0x600a94` if I put var outside from main() function?

Comment: @setevoy: It's called data-section, and it is where all `non static global`, `static global` and `static local` variables are located. The addresses of these variables are constant throughout the execution of your program. In contrast with those three "types", any `non static local` variable is located in the stack, and its address may change during the execution of your program, depending on the state of the stack at the point in time when the function (in which the variable is declared) is called.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are just missing one half of your pointer values. The correct format for printing pointers is `%p`, on machines with 64 bit addresses and 32 bit `int` this makes a "significant" difference.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix to the output what had been cut of by using 32bit `%x` on 64bit pointers, that is `7fff` and you find your var/s just above the stack's bottom: `7ffff79780000`.

Use `%p` to print pointers, by casting them to `void*` before:

```
printf("Address of var1 variable: %p\n", (void*) &var1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please also note that `var2` is already a pointer. `&var2` is still valid, as it seems...

These three are all the same, but the last is not very logic to me:

- `var2`
- `&var2[0]`
- `&var2`

Comment: Yes, really: `   printf("Address of var2 variable: %p\n", &var2  ); printf("Address of var2[0] variable: %p\n", &var2[0]  );` result `Address of var2 variable: 0x7fff9ad943c0 Address of var2[0] variable: 0x7fff9ad943c0`

Comment: "*... `var2` is already a pointer.*": No, `var2` isn't as pointer, it is an array. Passing it to a function (`printf()` here) makes the array decay to a pointer (to its 1st element).